# Starting FOREVER or PM2 as WWW-DATA from a PHP script

Tags: php, linux, node.js, ubuntu

I have a `nodejs` script named `script.js`.

```
var util = require('util'); 
var net = require("net"); 

process.on("uncaughtException", function(e) {
console.log(e);
});

var proxyPort = "40000"; 
var serviceHost = "1.2.3.4"; 
var servicePort = "50000"; 

net.createServer(function (proxySocket) {
    var connected = false;
    var buffers = new Array();
    var serviceSocket = new net.Socket();
    serviceSocket.connect(parseInt(servicePort), serviceHost);
    serviceSocket.pipe(proxySocket).pipe(serviceSocket);
    proxySocket.on("error", function (e) {
        serviceSocket.end();
    });
    serviceSocket.on("error", function (e) {
        console.log("Could not connect to service at host "
            + serviceHost + ', port ' + servicePort);
        proxySocket.end();
    });
    proxySocket.on("close", function(had_error) {
        serviceSocket.end();
    });
    serviceSocket.on("close", function(had_error) {
        proxySocket.end();
    });
}).listen(proxyPort);
```

I am runing it normally like `nodejs script.js`, but now i want to include `forever` or `pm2` functionalities as well. When i am `root` everything works smootly:

```
chmod -R 777 /home/nodejs/forever/;
-- give rights

watch -n 0.1 'ps ax | grep forever | grep -v grep'
-- watch forwarders (where i see if a forever is opened)

/usr/local/bin/forever -d -v --pidFile "/home/nodejs/forever/file.pid" --uid 'file' -p '/home/nodejs/forever/' -l '/home/nodejs/forever/file.log' -o '/home/nodejs/forever/file.log' -e '/home/nodejs/forever/file.log' -a start /etc/dynamic_ip/nodejs/proxy.js 41789 1.2.3.4:44481 414 file
-- open with forever

forever list
-- it is there, i can see it

forever stopall
-- kill them all
```

The problem is when i want to run the script from a `PHP` script with the `system` or `exec` functions :

```
sudo -u www-data /usr/local/bin/forever -d -v --pidFile "/home/nodejs/forever/file.pid" --uid 'file' -p '/home/nodejs/forever/' -l '/home/nodejs/forever/file.log' -o '/home/nodejs/forever/file.log' -e '/home/nodejs/forever/file.log' -a start /etc/dynamic_ip/nodejs/proxy.js 41789 1.2.3.4:44481 414 file
-- open as www-data (or i can do this just by accessing `http://1.2.3.4/test.php`, it is the same thing)

forever list
-- see if it is there, and it is not (i see it in watch)

forever stopall
-- says no forever is opened

kill PID_ID
-- the only way is to kill it by pid ... and on another server all of this works very well, can create and kill forevers from a php script when accessing it from web ... not know why
-- everything is in /etc/sudoers including /usr/local/bin/forever
```

Why is that? How can i solve this?

I also made some trick, created a user 'forever2', i created a `script.sh` with this content :

```
sudo su forever2 user123; /usr/local/bin/forever -d -v --pidFile "/home/nodejs/forever/file.pid" --uid 'file' -p '/home/nodejs/forever/' -l '/home/nodejs/forever/file.log' -o '/home/nodejs/forever/file.log' -e '/home/nodejs/forever/file.log' -a start /etc/dynamic_ip/nodejs/proxy.js 41789 1.2.3.4:44481 414 file;
```

where `user123` is not existent, is just a trick to exit the `shell` after execution. The script works, runs `forever`, i can close all forevers with the command `forever stopall` from `root`. When i try the same thing running the `http://1.2.3.4/test.php` or as `www-data` user i cannot close it from `root` or `www-data`, so not even this works.

I tried from `Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS`, `Ubuntu 14.04 LTS` , `Debian GNU/Linux 8` ... still the same thing.

Any ideeas?

Thanks.

Comment: You can't "see" forever processes running as another user, i.e. if you'd `sudo su www-data` and then would do `forever stopall` it _would_ work.

Comment: and if i do `sudo -u www-data forever stopall` why it dosen't work?

Comment: Yeah, good question. The only explanation I can think of is that forever spawns child processes and when using `sudo -u` only the main process is being tried to shut down as that user and the other processes are being shut down as the "current" user.

Comment: trust me i i tried to run with `forever2` and i have to addmit, if i am logged as `forever2` i can create and kill forevers while i am this user, but this would mean that the `script.sh` plan should work, right?

Comment: I'd think so. But if I understand it correctly, you can't do the `.sh` file trick with `www-data` instead of `forever2`?

Comment: what do you mean? to try `sudo su forever2 user123; /usr/local/bin/forever -d -v --pidFile "/home/nodejs/forever .... rest of the command`?? if so, u can't log with www-data ...

Comment: I have same problem: I run node program with forever via crontab @reboot ... of www-data user - and forever can't see this running processes and can't manage it. I even set global var for forever config folder - from root all works fine, but not from www-data. I think problem can be somewhere in forever config. Or, in some www-data user restrictions.

Comment: i made a new user `forever3` and i used `ssh php class` to log on `forever3` and open `forever`. I can also close and list with this tweak, the down side is that i have to wait +3-4 secs more, and the other server don't, an it will do a major unbalance in my cluster of servers ...

Answer (score 1):

If you are starting the process from within Apache or the web-server you are already as the `www-data` user, so doing a `sudo su` to the user context you already have is likely not necessary.

When you start this `forever` task you may also be required to shut the terminals/inputs and directly send to background.  Something like this:

```
// Assemble command
$cmd = '/usr/bin/forever';
$cmd.= ' -d -v --pidfile /tmp/my.pid'; // add other options
$cmd.= ' start';
$cmd.= ' /etc/dynamic_ip/nodejs/proxy.js';
// "magic" to get details
$cmd.= ' 2>&1 1>/tmp/output.log'; // Route STDERR to STDOUT; STDOUT to file
$cmd.= ' &'; // Send whole task to background.
system($cmd);
```

Now, there won't be any output here but you should have something in `/tmp/output.log` which could show why `forever` failed, or the script crashed.

If you've been running the script sometimes as root, then trying the same command as www-data you may also be running into a permissions on one or more files/directories created from the execution as root which now conflict when running as www-data.

Answer (score 1):

This is part of PHP security you say you're running it from a php script and your not your running it from Apache via a php script.

PHP web scripts should not have root access as such they run under the same permissions as Apache user `www-data`.

There are ways to prevent php running as root but run a task as root but it's a little hacky and I'm not going to share the code but I will explain so you can look into it. here is where to start

http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php

With a Proccess like this you can then execute a proc. Like your `script.js` via nodeJS using SUDO and then read stdOut and stdErr wait for password request then provide it by writing to stdIn for that process.

Don't forget in doing this the user `www-data` has to have a password and be in the sudoers list

Per the OPs Comment
Due to the way SUDO works the PATH does not appear to contain the path to the node executables `npm, node` so your best of building a .sh (bash script) and using sudo to run that.

You still need to monitor this process as it will still ask for a password

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo -u ec2-user -i
# change this to the path you want to run from
cd ~
/usr/local/bin/pm2 -v
```

Comment: trust me, i tried everything ... right now i am making a `socket server` that will not use the `www-data` user, just for this problem, imagine how ugly this got ...

Comment: i normally choose to use java for this sort of thing php is not designed to manage anything that is persistent

Comment: I succesfully managed to have the "apache user" to get the node version with this: 
sudo -u ec2-user /usr/local/bin/node -v
but thats it, I am unable to do the same with pm2
sudo -u ec2-user /usr/local/bin/pm2 -v  gets me this:
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory

Comment: This is because the pm2 application is looking for the node application and can't find node as the PATH variable wont be setup as your doing `sudo -u` your gonna have to do it as a chain of commands E.G build a bash script and run it with the sudo. i will add an update to this answer with it in