# Using PHP exec with forever just stops the script?

Tags: php, node.js, forever

So I currently have a script let's just call it foo.js 
I am attempting to use the following code to execute it with arg's and I have already attempted everything I can find on here eg: doing $output and checking what it says (It says forever running foo.js then that is where the line ends) if I type forever list nothing is being ran. If I run the script normally in node eg: using node instead of forever start it infinitely loads while running the script ofc. I tried nohup aswell :) 
If anyone can help it would be much appreciated.

Code:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
$argy = $_GET["arg1"];
$argx = $_GET["arg2"];
$argz = $_GET["arg3"];
exec("forever start foo.js $argy $argx $argz",$output);
print_r($output);
?>
<br>

</body>
</html>
```

Update #1: 
33mwarn[39m: --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms [33mwarn[39m: --spinSleepTime not set. Your script will exit if it does not stay up for at least 1000ms [32minfo[39m: Forever processing file: [90mfoo.js[39m fs.js:549 return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode); ^ Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/root/.forever/0ABS.log' at Error (native) at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:549:18) at Object.forever.startDaemon (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever/lib/forever.js:460:14) at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever/lib/forever/cli.js:319:15 at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever/lib/forever/cli.js:162:5 at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever/lib/forever.js:412:11 at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)

Comment: Why don't you simply dump `$_GET` to see what elements it actually contains?

Comment: It's not the elements that's the issue. I simply would like to exec the things obtained from the $_GET inside the forever cmd. The arguments are x-fered perfectly but for some reason it starts the script then I assume just terminates. Here is $output. Array ( [39m: Forever processing file: [90mfoojs[39m )

Comment: Sorry, but that comment makes your question even more unclear. Please take the time to revise your question (there is an `edit` link below it, _use it_) to describe in a more precise manner what it actually is you want to do. What do you mean by "would like to exec the things obtained from the $_GET"? What does the script output have to do with how it is called or executed?

Comment: Okay, sorry, I meant something completely different. Anyways I have gotten a better output Im updating the post with it now.

Comment: The issue is that `forever` can not be invoked under `www-data` user, executing the same script using terminal will executes normally, you may use work around using [`ssh2`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-exec.php) but this may be dangerous in some contexts

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Starting FOREVER or PM2 as WWW-DATA from a PHP script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33451674/starting-forever-or-pm2-as-www-data-from-a-php-script)

Comment: Yeah I see now, my bad. Thanks for the help guys :D Really appreciate it will be looking into alternatives.